# Securing REST API

Tags: rest, rest-security

I have a website which consumes the rest APIs exposed on the webserver.
This is content website and free to public. Thus, anybody can read the content by navigating on it (which call different REST APIs in the background). At the same time, I am worried that somebody could figure out my endponits from developer tools in the browser and call those (millions of times) to bring my server down. I need to secure my REST apis except from browsers. How do I go about this ?

Comment: If you don't have any `CORS` mechanism enabled you should be good, but....

Comment: Use a HTTP proxy in front of the REST service. This could be used to cache responses.

Comment: This is not a silver bullet but, how about using https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project  and test your site for red and yellow flags?

Answer (score 0):

I like to see the problem separated from your REST api.
Your api is a service on top of wich you'll want to build some security. Therefore, security is not actually affecting the design of your api.

One trivial thing to do is controlling the input flows. There are patterns associated with DOS or DDOS attacks that can be recognised to undertake counteractions. This is what [Intrusion Prevention Systems (IPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) do.

Please, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Application_front_end_hardware) and, if you are more interested in something deeper, [here](http://ro.ecu.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1054&context=ism).

If your requests are not authenticated (i.e. your apis are public) I think there's nothing more you can do.

Answer (score -1):

You can secure your HTTP endpoints by using SHA-256 cryptographic algorithms. SHA-256 is more secure and fast enough to be used to secure HTTP calls. [Here](https://developerfreak.blogspot.com/2022/03/secure-rest-apis-with-sha-256.html) is a good example of how can you secure your API endpoints by signing the request and response using SHA-256.

Comment: 1) The gist of the answer should be in the answer, not just linked to. 2) That's describing a signature authentication implementation. This is fairly useless if the client needs to know a secret key to produce the signature, since that secret key must be made available to any anonymous visitor. An attacker would be able to do this just as well as legitimate clients, it's just slightly more implementation work upfront.

Comment: Hi sorry @deceze for not following the answer rules, just to clarify the client doesn't need to share his secret key and he will only share his public key so there is no risk of being attacked.

Comment: Whatever key they share… the requester needs to know *a key* to produce a signature hash. Even anonymous visitors will need to know that key and the algorithm to produce the signature. So it must be exposed to anyone and everyone.